# C++ Big vector search item

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, erase

First time posting here and this is driving me crazy! I can't explain it really well,So i'll try giving an example.

I'm trying to retrieve a element in a very big ( 100k ) vector to erase it. Itterating trough it will take ages... so i tried this:

This is a small example of my list. Which is stored in my singleton Particle Emitter class.

```
vector<Particle> particles;
particles.reserve(100);
```

This is a stripped version of my Particle

```
class Particle
{
Particle:
~Particle:

void Delete
{
  int listNum = (this - &particles[0]);
  particles.erase(particles.begin+listNum);
}
};
```

This works fine and all, but i don't want to save every particle on the stack, so I want to change this

```
vector<Particle> particles;
```

into

```
vector<Particle*> particles;
```

Now my question: Is it still possible to delete and erase the particle from the list if the vector consists of Particle pointers?

I'm not sure if i'm clear with my question, but I'll hope you'll understand!

Or if someone knows a better performance wise solution, i'd like to hear it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `Particle` class should not be knowledgeable about what container is holding it.

Comment: How big is particle? If it is expensive to copy construct, then you should store as pointer, but use a pointer container (such as `boost::ptr_vector`), and I agree with chris, imbuing knowledge of the container to the class is not a good idea...

Comment: Also, to reduce search time, may be you can have a sorted vector?

Comment: "but i don't want to save every particle on the stack" the storage of an `std::vector` is on the heap.

Comment: @chris: Good advise in general, but sometimes you need to stray away from best practices for performance reasons.

Comment: Random erase in a 100K entries vector looks to me a pain either with a  `vector<particle>` (I assume `Particle` small: `O(1)` `doubles`) or with a  `vector<particle*>` because of the entry movement. How often you have to delete?

Comment: Using `erase()` in the middle of a `std::vector` will always be slow. Can you just copy `particles.back()` to `particles[listNum]` and then do `particles.pop_back()`?

Comment: Haven't reached 100k yet though, but it's an estimate on how much it should handle max. I delete often, because of the effects that i'm going to use.

Comment: Yes that is a good suggestion, but i still need to find the position of the current particle that i'm planning to delete.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you planning on using this `std::vector`?

You say iterating will take ages, but if your goal is to iterate over all values, you simply cannot do better than a contiguous array. You talk about deleting elements from the container, which suggests you need a dynamic array, which is exactly what `std::vector` is.

Regardless, you definitely do not want to store a vector of raw pointers. Your two options should be `std::vector<Particle>` (generally preferred) or `std::vector<unique_ptr<Particle>>` (C++11 only) if you measure and find performance lacking due to using certain operations. Depending on your use case, `std::map<Particle>` or `std::set<Particle>` may be good ideas, but we don't have enough information.

You are not storing any `Particle` on the stack. Every element in a `std::vector` is already in the free store ("the heap").

Your insertion and deletion code should have nothing to do with your `Particle` class, either. Inserting and deleting is an operation on your container, not on the contained elements.

To answer your question, we need to know a few things.

First, how big is `Particle`? This is probably the most important information.

Second, what are you doing with the container? Are you generally looking at every `Particle` and doing things with them, or are you searching for a particular `Particle` in your entire container? If you are searching, do you try and look up based on some kind of key (for instance, each `Particle` has a unique ID and you look up the whole `Particle` on that ID), or are you looking up to see if one `Particle` matches another (so in other words, you look up based on the identity of `Particle`)?

If you are looking up an individual `Particle`, then `std::set` should probably be your first choice for ease of use, as it allows a binary search. If your use case has you search for particles by key, then you'll want `std::map<Key, Particle>`.

If you have a bunch of Particles and you want to remove a few from the container, then the size of the object matters quite a bit. However, you'll generally want a `std::vector` for such a situation.

In short, I'll need more information to fully answer your question.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, will work on your suggestions first and see if I can make something from it!

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about putting your vector on the stack, why don't you try something like this:

```
vector <Particle> * particles = new vector <Particle>;
```

This will make the vector last until you `delete` it. Also, if you're concerned about performance issues, a `set` would be a good idea. This guarantees that all inserts and deletes will be logarithmic time, and that you won't have to use your own delete function. For even better performance in C++11, try `unordered_set`.

Comment: `std::vector` already allocates on the heap. Your change doesn't really accomplish anything.

Comment: Just realized that. However, since he seemed to be declaring it within a function, doing the `new/delete` method will preserve it for as long as he needs, if that's necessary.

Comment: Preserving it as long as needed should work anyway, particularly with C++11 move semantics. Also, the OP apparently declared it _globally_, that's horrible but definitely makes copy/moving unnecessary.

Comment: Haha, not globally but i put it in my particle Emitter class

Comment: There is no real advantage to storing a pointer to a std::vector rather than the std::vector itself. A std::vector typically allocates `sizeof(pointer) * 3` on the stack, regardless of how many elements are contained in the std::vector.